# Import animated mesh without a rigged skeleton / armature

Tags: animation, blender, unreal-4, asset-workflow

How can I import an animation of a mesh that was not animated using rigging, skeletons, or armatures from blender? There's got to be a way.

Comment: What kind of animation are you trying to import? Can you walk us through a concrete example of how you've authored this animation?

Comment: It's a simple gun mesh with a slider animation that cycles with moving edges and vertices on keyframes. Bones seem like overkill.

Comment: A bone would probably be more efficient actually. That way you only have to animate one set of transform properties rather than one per vertex

Comment: Ok so assume I want to animate several vertecies without regard to efficiency, and import the animation into unreal and run it in engine.

Comment: My reasoning may not make sense to anyone but me so let's not dive too deep into specifics. I'm sure there's a way. Importable keyframes? Or...?

Comment: You looked into [morph targets](https://www.google.com/search?q=unreal+morph+targets), I assume?